# Delete activity of a contact

Tags: activity

I have created few activities for a contact. I want delete one of the contact. When tried to delete, it is not showing proper screen after deleting the activity
[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean with the proper screen after deleting?

Comment: After deleting the activity it is loading summary tab instead of activity tab.

Comment: Does the activity gets deleted? If so the the delete functionality works but only the redirect is strange. You could file a bug report at http://issues.civicrm.org

Comment: You might also want to edit the post from " I want delete one of the contact." to " I want delete one of the activities." if that is what you meant to say

Answer (score 1):

This appears to have been fixed for version 4.7. After deleting an activity you remain on the 'Activities' tab for the contact. I tested this on http://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/